Filter collection mongoose
I make a request from the client to the server, where I pass the query parameters - search, memory, color
search - search by ProductName field
memory - search by memory field
color - search by color field
The search works well, but only if I pass these query parameters. But if they are not transmitted, then the response from the server comes empty.
async getOne(req, res, next) {
        try {
            // Filters
            const { search = '', color = '', memory = '' } = req.query

            const products = await ProductModel.find()
                .where('_id')
                .in(productsIds) // productsIds - Just an array of ids that I received in advance
                .skip(skip)
                .limit(limit)
                .and([{ productName: search }, { 'specs.memory': memory }, { color }])

            return res.status(200).json({ products, length: products.length})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' })
        }
    }


As I understand it, mongoose is looking for a strict match, but how can it be made to look for the occurrence of a parameter in a string
That's what I need:
I have a Product with ProductName: 'Test'
When search = "Te" returned this Product, and if search = "", it returned all Products

The issue you're encountering is because the .and clause in your Mongoose query requires all specified conditions to match exactly as they are provided. When your query parameters (search, color, memory) are empty strings, Mongoose tries to find documents that strictly match these empty strings, which likely results in no matches unless your documents actually have empty strings for those fields.
To achieve the desired behavior—whereby the presence of a query parameter filters the results, and the absence of a parameter returns all results—you should construct your query dynamically, only adding conditions for parameters that are provided and non-empty. Additionally, for partial matches (like your search parameter), you'll want to use regular expressions.
Here's how you could adjust your getOne function to implement this behavior:
async getOne(req, res, next) {
    try {
        // Filters
        const { search = '', color = '', memory = '' } = req.query;

        let queryConditions = [];

        // Add search condition if search query is provided and not empty
        if (search) {
            queryConditions.push({ productName: new RegExp(search, 'i') }); // 'i' for case-insensitive matching
        }

        // Add memory condition if memory query is provided and not empty
        if (memory) {
            queryConditions.push({ 'specs.memory': memory });
        }

        // Add color condition if color query is provided and not empty
        if (color) {
            queryConditions.push({ color: color });
        }

        const products = await ProductModel.find()
            .where('_id').in(productsIds) // Assuming productsIds is defined elsewhere
            .skip(skip) // Assuming skip is defined elsewhere
            .limit(limit) // Assuming limit is defined elsewhere
            .and(queryConditions.length > 0 ? queryConditions : [{}]); // If no conditions, match all documents

        return res.status(200).json({ products, length: products.length });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
    }
}

In this adjusted version, queryConditions is an array that starts empty and only gets conditions pushed into it if the corresponding query parameters are provided and non-empty. This way, if no parameters are provided, the .and clause effectively becomes .and([{}]), which matches all documents. For the search parameter, we use a regular expression to achieve partial, case-insensitive matching, which allows for the "occurrence of a parameter in a string" behavior you described.
